# Edit distance leetcode

Tags: recursion, dynamic-programming, edit-distance

So I am doing this question of EDIT DISTANCE and before going to DP approach I am trying to solve this question in recursive manner and I am facing some logical error, please help....
Here is my code -

```
class Solution {
public int minDistance(String word1, String word2) {
    int n=word1.length();
    int m=word2.length();
    if(m<n)
   return Solve(word1,word2,n,m);
     else
                return Solve(word2,word1,m,n);
}
private int Solve(String word1,String word2,int n,int m){
     if(n==0||m==0)
        return Math.abs(n-m);
    
    if(word1.charAt(n-1)==word2.charAt(m-1))
        return 0+Solve(word1,word2,n-1,m-1);
    
    else{
        //insert
        int insert = 1+Solve(word1,word2,n-1,m);
        
        //replace
        int replace = 1+Solve(word1,word2,n-1,m-1);
        
        //delete
        int delete = 1+Solve(word1,word2,n-1,m);
        
        int max1 = Math.min(insert,replace);
        return Math.min(max1,delete);
    }
}
```

}

here I am checking the last element of both the strings if both the characters are equal then simple moving both string to n-1 and m-1 resp.
Else
Now I am having 3 cases of insertion , deletion and replace ,and between these 3 I have to find minima.
If I am replacing the character then simply I moved the character to n-1 & m-1.
**If I am inserting the character from my logic I think I should insert the character at the last of smaller length string and move the pointer to n-1 and m**
**To delete the element I think I should delete the element from the larger length String that's why I move pointer to n-1 and m but I think I am making mistake here please help**.

Leetcode is giving me wrong answer for word1 = "plasma" and word2 = "altruism".

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the recursive expression for the insert-case is the same as for the delete-case.

Reasoning further, it turns out the one for the insert-case is wrong. In that case we choose to resolve the letter in word2 (at index `m-1`) through insertion, so it should not be considered any more during the recursive process. On the other hand the considered letter in word1 could still be matched with *another* letter in word2, so that letter should still be considered during the recursive process.

That means that `m` should be decremented, not `n`.

So change:

```
int insert = 1+Solve(word1,word2,n-1,m);
```

to:

```
int insert = 1+Solve(word1,word2,n,m-1);
```

...and it will work. Then remains to add the memoization for getting a good efficiency.

Answer (score 0):

Python clean DP based solution,

```py
class Solution:
    
    def minDistance(self, word1: str, word2: str) -> int:
        
        return self.edit_distance(word1, word2)
    
    
    @cache
    def edit_distance(self, s, t):
        
        # Edge conditions
        if len(s) == 0:
            return len(t)
        
        if len(t) == 0:
            return len(s)
        
        
        # If 1st char matches
        if s[0] == t[0]:
            return self.edit_distance(s[1:], t[1:])
        
        
        else:
            
            return min(
                1 + self.edit_distance(s[1:], t), # delete
                1 + self.edit_distance(s, t[1:]), # insert
                1 + self.edit_distance(s[1:], t[1:]) # replace
            )
```